# how to draw staircase diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw the figure given below.

[image]

Comment: Slowly and patiently?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the following example : http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/plane-partition/

Comment: This is your second question, without showing any efford, or asking anything sensible. What have you tried, and what problems do you have?

Comment: I suggest to draw your figure, quickly, `InkScape` or `Ipe`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254010/placing-text-on-face-of-3d-cube

Answer (score 15):

Here's an example of what you might do in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) using the `luamplib` interface.  It's just about usable for this sort of isometric fake 3D, but you should try [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) for serious TeX-friendly 3D work.  Or you can follow some of the excellent Tikz examples [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    numeric r, t;
    r = 7/16;
    u = 1cm;

    path ff, tt, ss;
    ff = unitsquare scaled u;
    tt = ff slanted r yscaled r;
    ss = tt reflectedabout (left,right) rotated 90;

    picture front, top, side;
    front = image( fill ff withcolor .8 [blue,white]; draw ff );
    top   = image( fill tt withcolor .95 [blue,white]; draw tt );
    side  = image( fill ss withcolor .65 [blue,white]; draw ss );

    vardef punto(expr x, y, z) = (x*u+r*z*u, y*u+r*z*u) enddef;

    draw front shifted punto ( 1, 1, 3); 
    draw front shifted punto ( 0, 1, 3); 
    draw front shifted punto ( 1, 0, 3); 

    draw top   shifted punto ( 0, 1, 2);
    draw side  shifted punto ( 0, 1, 2);
    draw top   shifted punto ( 1, 0, 2);
    draw side  shifted punto ( 1, 0, 2);

    draw front shifted punto ( 1,-1, 2);
    draw front shifted punto (-1, 1, 2);

    draw side  shifted punto (-1, 1, 1);
    draw top   shifted punto (-1, 1, 1);
    draw top   shifted punto ( 0, 1, 1);
    draw side  shifted punto ( 1, 0, 1);
    draw side  shifted punto ( 1,-1, 1);
    draw top   shifted punto ( 1,-1, 1);

    draw front shifted punto (-1, 0, 1);
    draw front shifted punto ( 0, 0, 1);
    draw front shifted punto ( 0,-1, 1);

    draw side  shifted punto (-1, 1, 0);
    draw side  shifted punto (-1, 0, 0);
    draw top   shifted punto (-1, 0, 0);
    draw side  shifted punto ( 0,-1, 0);
    draw top   shifted punto ( 0,-1, 0);
    draw top   shifted punto ( 1,-1, 0);

    draw punto ( 2, 2, 4) -- punto (-2, 2, 4) 
      -- punto (-2, 2, 0) -- punto (-2, -2, 0) 
      -- punto ( 2,-2, 0) -- punto ( 2, -2, 4)
      -- cycle ; 

    draw punto (2,-2,0) -- punto (2,-1,0);
    draw punto (2,2,3) -- punto (2,2,4);
    draw punto (-2,2,0) -- punto (-1,2,0);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good you draw.

Answer (score 13):

You can utilize `tikz-3dplot` for 3D diagrams. The following output is yielded by the following code.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0} %<- rotate around (z,y,z)
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[tdplot_rotated_coords,
       plane/.style={thick, fill=white!90}, 
        grid/.style={very thick,black},
        boxA/.style={thin,fill=gray!90},
        boxB/.style={thin,fill=gray!20},
 sphereWhite/.style={ball color = white},
 sphereBlack/.style={ball color = black}]

\draw[plane] 
(0,0,4) -- (4,0,4) -- (4,1,4) -- (2,1,4) -- 
(2,2,4) -- (1,2,4) -- (1,4,4) -- (0,4,4) -- cycle;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[plane] 
(4,0,0) -- (4,0,4) -- (4,1,4) -- (4,1,2) -- 
(4,2,2) -- (4,2,1) -- (4,4,1) -- (4,4,0) -- cycle;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[plane] 
(0,4,0) -- (4,4,0) -- (4,4,1) -- (2,4,1) -- 
(2,4,2) -- (1,4,2) -- (1,4,4) -- (0,4,4) -- cycle;

\draw[boxA] (2,1,4) -- (3,1,4) -- (3,1,3) -- (2,1,3) -- cycle;
\draw[boxA] (3,1,4) -- (4,1,4) -- (4,1,3) -- (3,1,3) -- cycle;
\draw[boxA] (3,1,3) -- (4,1,3) -- (4,1,2) -- (3,1,2) -- cycle;
\draw[boxA] (3,2,2) -- (4,2,2) -- (4,2,1) -- (3,2,1) -- cycle;
\draw[boxA] (1,2,4) -- (2,2,4) -- (2,2,3) -- (1,2,3) -- cycle;
\draw[boxA] (1,3,3) -- (2,3,3) -- (2,3,2) -- (1,3,2) -- cycle;
\draw[boxA] (2,3,3) -- (3,3,3) -- (3,3,2) -- (2,3,2) -- cycle;
\draw[boxA] (2,3,2) -- (3,3,2) -- (3,3,1) -- (2,3,1) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (1,2,4) -- (1,3,4) -- (1,3,3) -- (1,2,3) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (1,3,4) -- (1,4,4) -- (1,4,3) -- (1,3,3) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (1,3,3) -- (1,4,3) -- (1,4,2) -- (1,3,2) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (2,3,2) -- (2,4,2) -- (2,4,1) -- (2,3,1) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (2,1,4) -- (2,2,4) -- (2,2,3) -- (2,1,3) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (3,1,3) -- (3,2,3) -- (3,2,2) -- (3,1,2) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (3,2,3) -- (3,3,3) -- (3,3,2) -- (3,2,2) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (3,2,2) -- (3,3,2) -- (3,3,1) -- (3,2,1) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (3,3,1) -- (4,3,1) -- (4,4,1) -- (3,4,1) -- cycle;
\draw[boxB] (2,2,3) -- (3,2,3) -- (3,3,3) -- (2,3,3) -- cycle;

\shade[sphereWhite] (4,1,4) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereWhite] (2,2,4) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereWhite] (1,4,4) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereWhite] (4,2,2) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereWhite] (3,3,3) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereWhite] (4,4,1) circle (0.08cm);
\shade[sphereWhite] (2,4,2) circle (0.08cm);

\shade[sphereBlack] (2,1,3) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereBlack] (1,2,3) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereBlack] (3,1,2) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereBlack] (3,2,1) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereBlack] (2,3,1) circle (0.08cm); 
\shade[sphereBlack] (1,3,2) circle (0.08cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful. I like it. My congratulations.

Comment: @Sebastiano, glad you liked it.

Comment: You deserve a praise you have taken so long I guess.