# How to add a rotated text below a cube?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a cube as given below. I want to add a text attribute for the cube, such that the text  below the cube is rotated along with the figure

[image]

This is my definition of the cube

```
  \tikzset{
    annotated cuboid/.pic={
      \tikzset{%
        every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
        /cuboid/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [\cubeline,every edge/.append style={pic actions,\cubeback, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
      (0,0,0) coordinate (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b-\cubelabel) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g-\cubelabel) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (d-\cubelabel) -- cycle;

    },
    /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
    /cuboid/.cd,
    width/.store in=\cubex,
    height/.store in=\cubey,
    depth/.store in=\cubez,
    units/.store in=\cubeunits,
    scale/.store in=\cubescale,
    label/.store in=\cubelabel,
    line/.store in=\cubeline,
    backline/.store in=\cubeback,
    width=10,
    height=10,
    depth=10,
    units=cm,
    scale=.1,   
    line=draw,
    backline=densely dashed
  }
```

My full code (MWE):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
  \tikzset{
    annotated cuboid/.pic={
      \tikzset{%
        every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
        /cuboid/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [\cubeline,every edge/.append style={pic actions, \cubeback, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
      (0,0,0) coordinate (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b-\cubelabel) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g-\cubelabel) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (d-\cubelabel) -- cycle;
      ;
    },
    /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
    /cuboid/.cd,
    width/.store in=\cubex,
    height/.store in=\cubey,
    depth/.store in=\cubez,
    units/.store in=\cubeunits,
    scale/.store in=\cubescale,
    label/.store in=\cubelabel,
    line/.store in=\cubeline,
    backline/.store in=\cubeback,
    width=10,
    height=10,
    depth=10,
    units=cm,
    scale=.1,
    line=draw,
    backline=densely dashed,
  }
\newcommand{\cuboid}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \pic [#1] at (0,0) {annotated cuboid={#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\tikzstyle{cubecontainer}=[outer sep = 0pt, inner sep= 0pt]
\tikzstyle{connectarrow}=[-{Triangle[angle=60:0pt 2]}, line width= 10pt, shorten >=3mm,shorten <=3mm, draw=gray!60]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[cubecontainer] (a) at (0,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}{label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
%\node[cubecontainer] (b) at (2,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}{label=B, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
%\node[cubecontainer] (c) at (5,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}{label=C, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
%%\node[draw,dotted,fit=(a) (b) (c)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a node below?

Comment: Node is so expensive. I have many cubes, so that is reason why I need add a attribute for that

Comment: `\pgftext` is less expensive. And `\hbox` plus `\pgfqboxsynced` is even less expensive. And `\hbox` plus `\pgfqbox` is way too cheap.

Comment: Does my answer here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254010/placing-text-on-face-of-3d-cube/254236#254236, fit your need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a simple node like this: `\node [below of=a, node distance=1.4cm,rotate=45,xshift=-1cm]  (critical) {20x30x20};` is to expensive for you, you can set the label inside `tikzset` cubecontainer, for rotation you can use `\rotatebox{45}{#1}`. `#1` is the label, defined in the document:

```
\tikzset{cubecontainer/.style={outer sep= 0pt, inner sep= 0pt,label={265:\rotatebox{45}{#1}}}
}%optional with red background ... [fill=red]265 ....
```

`265` is the positioning angle, counted anticlockwise from 0=east to 360=east. (By a square: 0=east, 90=north, 180=west, 270=south,... )

... and use it with labeling the node with label = `20x20x30` (`\node[cubecontainer=20x20x30]`):

```
\node[cubecontainer=20x20x30] (a) at (0,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}{label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
```

.

---

**EDIT:** *2.Verison of `cubecontainer` - Change font size with the following `cubecontainer/.style`*

```
\tikzset{cubecontainer/.style={outer sep= 0pt, inner sep= 0pt,label={265:\rotatebox{45}{\Huge #1}}} }
```

---

1. Version:

[image]

2. Version: font size (\Huge)

*(Comparison of the first(left) and second version(right))*

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
  \tikzset{
    annotated cuboid/.pic={
      \tikzset{%
        every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
        /cuboid/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [\cubeline,every edge/.append style={pic actions, \cubeback, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
      (0,0,0) coordinate (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b-\cubelabel) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g-\cubelabel) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (d-\cubelabel) -- cycle;
      ;
    },
    /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
    /cuboid/.cd,
    width/.store in=\cubex,
    height/.store in=\cubey,
    depth/.store in=\cubez,
    units/.store in=\cubeunits,
    scale/.store in=\cubescale,
    label/.store in=\cubelabel,
    line/.store in=\cubeline,
    backline/.store in=\cubeback,
    width=10,
    height=10,
    depth=10,
    units=cm,
    scale=.1,
    line=draw,
    backline=densely dashed,
  }
\newcommand{\cuboid}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \pic [#1] at (0,0) {annotated cuboid={#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\tikzset{cubecontainer/.style={outer sep= 0pt, inner sep= 0pt,label={[fill=white]265:\rotatebox{45}{#1}}}
}
%\tikzset{cubecontainer/.style={outer sep= 0pt, inner sep= 0pt,label={265:\rotatebox{45}{\Huge #1}}} }
\tikzstyle{connectarrow}=[-{Triangle[angle=60:0pt 2]}, line width= 10pt, shorten >=3mm,shorten <=3mm, draw=gray!60]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[cubecontainer=20x20x30] (a) at (0,0) {\cuboid{fill=cyan!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black}{label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
%\node [below of=a, node distance=1.4cm,rotate=45,xshift=-1cm]  (critical) {20x30x20};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution. How can I change the label size. It means the number font size?

Comment: @user8264 you could use `font size` `\Huge`,`\footnotesize` or `\tiny`... with `\tikzset{cubecontainer/.style={outer sep= 0pt, inner sep= 0pt,label={265:\rotatebox{45}{\Huge #1}}} }`. I have updated my answer.